# Pandas new column when IDs repeat

Tags: python, pandas

Hello community,

I'm looking to create a new column with a list of unique medications for each ID.

I have a bit of a weird/complicated data, because my IDs repeat:

| ID | Medication |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | h |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | c |

Some IDs have a row for each medication (ID #1), some IDs have duplicate medications (ID #3) as well as non duplicated medications.

I would like to create a new column with a list of all unique medications for each ID:

| ID | Medication | Medications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a, b, c |
| 1 | b | a, b, c |
| 1 | c | a, b, c |
| 2 | h | h |
| 3 | a | a, c |
| 3 | a | a, c |
| 3 | c | a, c |

Would anyone know how to create this?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind having a list, instead of commas seperated strings, you can use `.unique()` with `.map`

```
df['Medications'] = df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')['Medication'].unique())

   ID Medication Medications
0   1          a   [a, b, c]
1   1          b   [a, b, c]
2   1          c   [a, b, c]
3   2          h         [h]
4   3          a      [a, c]
5   3          a      [a, c]
6   3          c      [a, c]
```

---

if strings are a must, you can `.drop_duplicates` first then apply a map

```
df['Medications'] = df['ID'].map(df.drop_duplicates(
          subset=['ID','Medication'])\
          .groupby('ID')['Medication'].agg(','.join))

   ID Medication Medications
0   1          a       a,b,c
1   1          b       a,b,c
2   1          c       a,b,c
3   2          h           h
4   3          a         a,c
5   3          a         a,c
6   3          c         a,c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want strings:

```
df["Medications"] = df.groupby("ID")["Medication"].transform(
    lambda x: ", ".join(x.unique())
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Medication Medications
0   1          a     a, b, c
1   1          b     a, b, c
2   1          c     a, b, c
3   2          h           h
4   3          a        a, c
5   3          a        a, c
6   3          c        a, c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Medications"] = (df.groupby("ID")
                       .Medication
                       .unique()
                       .agg(", ".join)
                       .reindex(df.ID).values)
```

`agg`regrating the `unique` values with `join` & `,` and then putting it back with `reindex`

to get

```
   ID Medication Medications
0   1          a     a, b, c
1   1          b     a, b, c
2   1          c     a, b, c
3   2          h           h
4   3          a        a, c
5   3          a        a, c
6   3          c        a, c
```